# [Verilog]ISE error:HDLCompiler:806

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

I keep getting errors below in ISE, and can not figure out the real problems. anyone has any clues?

error messages:

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 29: Syntax error near "posedge".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 39: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 43: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 47: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 50: Syntax error near "end".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 54: Syntax error near "posedge".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 64: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 68: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 72: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 75: Syntax error near "end".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 88: Syntax error near "posedge".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 98: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 102: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 106: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 109: Syntax error near "end".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 113: Syntax error near "posedge".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 123: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 127: Syntax error near "<=".
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\Ray\Documents\project\QFC\QFC_A.v" Line 131: Syntax error near "<=".
```

and here is my code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module QFC_A #
(
    parameter SPI_CYCLE   = 100000,
    parameter MASTER_ID   = 8'h66,
    parameter SLAVE_ID    = 8'h66
)

(
    input i_axi_lite_s_aclk,
    input i_rst,
    input i_din,
    output o_en,
    output o_dout
);



reg [255:0] r_frame_message;
reg [3:0] r_cnt_message;
wire [31:0] w_frame_word_message;
wire w_message_rd_en;
wire w_id_match_message;
wire w_message_empty;
wire w_message_ready;


always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_frame_message <= 256'h0;
            end
        else
            begin
                if (w_id_match_message & (r_cnt_message != 4'hf))
                    begin
                    r_frame_message <= {224'h0, w_frame_word_message};
                    end
                else if (w_message_rd_en & w_message_empty)
                    begin
                        r_frame_message <= 256'h0;
                    end
                else if (w_message_rd_en)
                    begin
                        r_frame_message <= {r_frame_message[223:0], w_frame_word_message};
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_id_match_message = (w_frame_word_message[23:16] == MASTER_ID)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_cnt_message <= 4'h0;
            end
        else if (w_message_rd_en)
            begin
                if (w_id_match_message)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_message <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else if (r_cnt_message == 4'hf)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_message <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        r_cnt_message <= r_cnt_message + 4'h1;
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_message_ready = (r_cnt_message == 4'hf & ~w_send_ready)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;  

reg [255:0] r_frame_data;
reg [3:0] r_cnt_data;
wire [31:0] w_frame_word_data;
wire w_data_rd_en;
wire w_id_match_data;
wire w_data_empty;
wire w_data_ready;


always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_frame_data <= 256'h0;
            end
        else
            begin
                if (w_id_match_data & (r_cnt_data != 4'hf))
                    begin
                        r_frame_data <= {224'h0, w_frame_word_data};
                    end
                else if (w_data_rd_en & w_data_empty)
                    begin
                        r_frame_data <= 256'h0;
                    end
                else if (w_data_rd_en)
                    begin
                        r_frame_data <= {r_frame_data[223:0], w_frame_word_data};
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_id_match_data = (w_frame_word_data[23:16] == MASTER_ID)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_cnt_data <= 4'h0;
            end
        else if (w_data_rd_en)
            begin
                if (w_id_match_data)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_data <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else if (r_cnt_data == 4'hf)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_data <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        r_cnt_data <= r_cnt_data + 4'h1;
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_data_ready = (r_cnt_data == 4'hf & ~w_send_ready)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;    

reg [255:0] r_frame_rec;
reg [3:0] r_cnt_rec;
wire[31:0] w_frame_word_rec;
wire w_rec_en;
wire w_id_match_rec;
wire w_rec_ready;
wire w_rec_success;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_frame_rec <= 256'h0;
            end
        else
            begin
                if (w_id_match_rec & (r_cnt_rec != 4'hf))
                    begin
                        r_frame_rec <= {224'h0, w_frame_word_rec};
                    end
                else if (w_rec_en)
                    begin
                        r_frame_rec <= {r_frame_rec[223:0], w_frame_word_rec};
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_id_match_rec = (w_frame_word_rec[23:16] == SLAVE_ID)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_cnt_rec <= 4'h0;
            end
        else if (w_rec_en)
            begin
                if (w_id_match_rec)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_rec <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else if (r_cnt_rec == 4'hf)
                    begin
                        r_cnt_rec <= 4'h0;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        r_cnt_rec <= r_cnt_rec + 4'h1;
                    end
            end
    end

assign w_rec_ready = (r_cnt_rec == 4'hf)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;      
assign w_rec_success = ((w_rec_ready) & (r_frame_rec[251] == 1'b1) & (checksum(r_frame_rec[239:16]) == r_frame_rec[15:0]))? 1'b1 : 1'b0;    

reg [2:0] r_current_state;
reg [2:0] r_next_state;
reg [16:0] r_cycle_timer;
reg [14:0] r_trans_timer;
reg [1:0] r_cycle_s;
reg [223:0] r_payload;
reg [255:0] r_frame_send;
wire w_cycle;
wire w_cycle_pos;
wire w_state_start;
localparam IDLE          = 3'h0;
localparam SEND_MSG      = 3'h1;
localparam RESEND_MSG    = 3'h2;
localparam SEND_DATA     = 3'h3;
localparam RCG_ACK       = 3'h4;
localparam CHANGE_TLG    = 3'h5;
localparam ABORT_MSG     = 3'h6;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if (i_rst)
            begin
                r_cycle_timer <= 16'h0;
            end
        else if (r_cycle_timer < SPI_CYCLE)
            begin
                r_cycle_timer <= r_cycle_timer + 16'h1;
            end
        else
            begin
                r_cycle_timer <= 16'h0;
            end
    end

assign w_cycle = (r_cycle_timer == SPI_CYCLE)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

always @ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)
    begin
        if(i_rst)
            begin
                r_cycle_s <= 2'h0;
            end
        else
            begin
                r_cycle_s <= {r_cycle_s[0], w_cycle};
            end
    end

assign w_cycle_pos = (~r_cycle_s[1] & r_cycle_s[0]);


function reg [15:0] checksum (input reg [223:0] r_frame)
    begin
        integer i;
        reg [15:0] r_sum_1;
        reg [15:0] r_sum_2;

        r_sum_1 = 16'hff;
        r_sum_2 = 16'hff;
        for (i = 0; i < 28; i++)
            begin
                r_sum_1 = r_sum_1 + r_frame[(223-8*i)-:8];
                r_sum_2 = r_sum_1 + r_sum_2;
                if (i == 20)
                    begin
                        r_sum_1 = ( r_sum_1 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_1 & 8'hff);
                        r_sum_2 = ( r_sum_2 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_2 & 8'hff);
                    end
            end
        r_sum_1 = ( r_sum_1 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_1 & 8'hff);
        r_sum_2 = ( r_sum_2 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_2 & 8'hff);
        r_sum_1 = ( r_sum_1 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_1 & 8'hff);
        r_sum_2 = ( r_sum_2 >> 8 ) + ( r_sum_2 & 8'hff);
        checksum = (r_sum_1 << 8) | r_sum_2;
    end
endfunction



always @ (*)
    begin
        case (r_current_state)
            IDLE:               begin
                                    r_next_state = SEND_DATA;
                                    r_frame_send = {8'h90, MASTER_ID, 240'h0};
                                end
            SEND_MSG:           begin
                                    r_next_state = RCG_ACK;
                                    if (w_state_start)
                                        begin
                                            w_message_rd_en = 1'b1;
                                            w_send_ready = 1'b0;
                                            w_state_start = 1'b0;
                                        end
                                    if (r_frame_message == 256'h0)
                                        begin
                                            w_message_rd_en = 1'b0;
                                            r_frame_send = {r_frame_send[], MASTER_ID, 240'h0};
                                        end
                                    else if
                                end
            RCG_ACK:            begin
                                    if (w_rec_success)
                                        begin
                                            r_next_state = CHANGE_TLG;
                                        end
                                    else if (r_resend_cnt == 2'b11)
                                            begin
                                                r_next_state = ABORT_MSG;
                                            end
                                end
        endcase
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely cause of this error is from the `&` in `@ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk & posedge i_rst)`. It is illegal syntax and I am guessing it is confusing the parser, making the error appear by the non-blocking assignment (`<=`). Change these `&` to `or` (I believe IEEE 1364-2001 also supports `,` as a sensitivity list separator but I do not have my LRM on hand to validate).

Eg: `@ (posedge i_axi_lite_s_aclk or posedge i_rst)`

There are plenty of other syntax errors. Missing semicolon in the function header, dangling `else if`, undeclared identifiers, etc. I'm not going to fix them for you.

<sub>FYI:</sub>

`&` is a bitwise and operator, which is different then the logical and operator `&&`. You are using `&` in places where `&&` would be recommended. I suggest you study the differences between logical and bitwise operators.

For many synthesizers using `? :` creates an explicit 2-to-1 mux. In all the cases you use `? :` the select value is the same as the output value. So you may just be wasting space.

I would suggest changing `assign w_message_ready = (r_cnt_message == 4'hf & ~w_send_ready)? 1'b1 : 1'b0;` to `assign w_message_ready = (r_cnt_message == 4'hf && !w_send_ready);`. Functionally they are identical, but the latter is more explicit and concise.

Comment: thank you for your help. it just an unfinished code. and I think your suggestion for ?: part is helpful. BTW, i know & is bitwise and, but is there any difference between & and && when coming to only 1-bit operation?

Comment: Functional, where both sides of an `&` are single bit is the same as if it was with a `&&`. If one is not single bit then sign extinction happens. Some really old tools use to give better performance and smaller logic with `&&`; I do not know how much of an issue it is with modern tools, but probably negligible. Various architects, methodologists, and synthesis gurus I've talked with all recommend using logical operators in most circumstances, use bitwise operators where necessary. At minimum it helps with code readability by not having to look up the bit width for mental logical or bitwise.